# как создать несколько вебсокетов

Tags: python, websocket

Пишу приложение которое подключается к серверу.Из за ограничения сервера я могу отправить 40 подписок на одно подключение. Приходиться создавать несколько переменных websocket.Можно ли как то автоматизировать создание вебсокетов или как то упростить их создание, что бы код не повторялся, так как нужно около 15 подключений, что бы отправить 600 подписок. Мой код примерно таков:

```
import websocket
import json
import time



def on_open(ws):
    ws.send(json.dumps({
        "op": "subscribe",
        "args": [
    {
        "instType": "SPOT",
        "channel": "trade",
        "instId": "ETHUSDT"
    }
    ]
    }))


def on_open2(ws):
    ws.send(json.dumps({
        "op": "subscribe",
        "args": [
    {
        "instType": "SPOT",
        "channel": "trade",
        "instId": "BTCUSDT"
    }
    ]
    }))


def on_message2(ws, message):
    try:
        print(message)
    except:
        # если ошибка доступа к результату
        print(message)


def on_message(ws, message):
    try:
    
        print(message)
    except:
        # если ошибка доступа к результату
        print(message)


def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print(f'сработала функция on_close {close_status_code}')


def on_error(ws, message):
    print(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.bitget.com/v2/ws/public",

                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_close=on_close,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_open=on_open
                                )
    ws1 = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.bitget.com/v2/ws/public",

                                 on_message=on_message2,
                                 on_open=on_open2
                                 )


    ws.run_forever()
    ws1.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws, instId):
    ws.send(json.dumps({
        "op": "subscribe",
        "args": [
            {
                "instType": "SPOT",
                "channel": "trade",
                "instId": instId
            }
        ]
    }))

def on_message(ws, message):
    try:
        print(message)
    except:
        print(message)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print(f'сработала функция on_close {close_status_code}')

def on_error(ws, message):
    print(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instIds = ["ETHUSDT", "BTCUSDT"]
    websocket_apps = []

    for instId in instIds:
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.bitget.com/v2/ws/public",
                                    on_message=lambda ws, msg: on_message(ws, msg),
                                    on_close=on_close,
                                    on_error=on_error,
                                    on_open=lambda ws: on_open(ws, instId)
                                    )
        websocket_apps.append(ws)

    for ws_app in websocket_apps:
        ws_app.run_forever()
```

Дополнение:

```
import websocket
import json
import threading
import time

def on_open(ws, instId):
    ws.send(json.dumps({
        "op": "subscribe",
        "args": [
            {
                "instType": "SPOT",
                "channel": "trade",
                "instId": instId
            }
        ]
    }))

def on_message(ws, message):
    try:
        print(message)
    except:
        print(message)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print(f'сработала функция on_close {close_status_code}')

def on_error(ws, message):
    print(message)

def run_socket(instId):
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ws.bitget.com/v2/ws/public",
                                on_message=lambda ws, msg: on_message(ws, msg),
                                on_close=on_close,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_open=lambda ws: on_open(ws, instId)
                                )
    ws.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    instIds = ["ETHUSDT", "BTCUSDT"]
    websocket_threads = []

    for instId in instIds:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run_socket, args=(instId,))
        websocket_threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
```

Comment: ,спасибо, буду разбираться, а можете подсказать как при таком варианте отправлять пинг на все подключения?Из документации run_forever(ping_interval=25,ping_timeout=5,ping_payload=('ping'))не работает

Comment: ws.send_ping() - как-то так вроде 

Comment: помоему в этом цикле for ws_app in websocket_apps:  ws_app.run_forever() вторая итерация не проходит, что бы запустить второй вебсокет.Во всяом случае в вашем коде всеравно одна подписка создается из списка instIds = ["ETHUSDT", "BTCUSDT"]

Comment: Видно надо создавать каждый сокет в отдельном потоке, но сама идея +- останется такой же.

Comment: Дополнил еще одним вариантом с потоками.

Comment: я понял ваше дополнение, спасибо

Comment: подскажите для чего нужен список websocket_threads в вашем дополнении?

Comment: В данном примере для красоты. Но к примеру: есть несколько потоков(как у нас), и вам нужно проверять, завершены ли они, или если вы хотите отправить им сигнал для остановки или ещё что-то поделать с конкретным потоком, то у вас будет такая возможность через этот список. Но если такой функционал вам не нужен, то можно смело это вырезать.

Comment: подскажите, как в таком случае сделать переподключение к вебсокетам в случае разрыва связи?в оф. документации только пример как я понял для главного потока